# Need help in C++ syntax

Tags: c++

```
#define FIRST 'a'
#define LAST  'd'
#define ALL  ((1 << (LAST-FIRST+1)) - 1)

int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    s1 = "aabcd";
    s2 = "caabd";
    // getline(cin, s1);
    // getline(cin, s2);

    // Build masks
    int mask[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};
    for (char c = FIRST; c <= LAST; ++c)
    {
        auto it1 = s1.begin(), it2 = s2.begin();
        bool done = false, fail = false;
        int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};
        mask[c] = ALL;
        // cout << "c:" << c << " " << ALL << " " <<  mask[c] << '\n';
        do {
            // Count characters until next match for c
            while (it1 != s1.end() && *it1 != c) ++count[(unsigned char)*it1++];
```

Can someone explain how the last sentence works `(while (it1 != s1.end() && *it1 != c) ++count[(unsigned char)*it1++];` in layman terms. Also, `count[1 << CHAR_BIT]`.  How do I print the contents of the `count[]` out?

Comment: especially the term ++count[(unsigned char)*it1++.  what does this do?

Comment: ++count[x] will increment the value of array count at position x

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We expect *one* question at a time, and it is not generally possible to just "explain" something because *we don't know why you don't understand it already*. More broadly: if you have trouble understanding a line of code, you should try to break it down into smaller pieces; if you find a specific thing that you don't understand, then [try to look it up yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), before asking a *specific* question.

Comment: The short answer: it increments the count for the character that the iterator `it1` references.  Your application is basically counting counting the occurrences in strings.  The `while` loop at the end traverses the characters of the string, stopping when it either reaches the end of the string, or the current character matches the one specified in the `for` loop.  The `++count[...]` part is just updating the count for whatever character `*it1` is referencing at the time.

Comment: Also: if this is someone else's code - especially if it is code from a textbook or other reference - the best person to ask about the meaning of the code is *the person who wrote it*. For a textbook, this means (re)reading the surrounding text in the chapter.

Comment: Oh I recognize that code.  I wrote it yesterday as a demonstration example for my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645855/1553090) to an algorithm question you posted.

Comment: it1++ looks like an iterator over the string s1, you are taking the next letter. The precedence is important. I don’t remember the rules, try to print it :)

Comment: @paddy That was some answer! :-)

Comment: Yeah I put a lot of effort into explaining exactly how it works, with examples, and then provided code to show it working.  Kinda sad to see this question now not even acknowledging that effort, nor asking for clarification on the answer itself.

Comment: Oh, I just realized this is being asked by a different person.  How strange.  I wonder if I've just done an entire class's homework for them or something...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that code as part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645855/1553090).

The part you're asking about is this:

```
auto it1 = s1.begin();
int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};

do {
    while (it1 != s1.end() && *it1 != c) ++count[(unsigned char)*it1++];
} while (...);
```

First, it obtains an iterator to the beginning of string `s1`.  It will be used to walk through the string.

```
auto it1 = s1.begin();
```

Then it intitializes a histogram as the array `count` which holds one integer for every possible character, and all values are initialized to zero.

```
int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};
```

Let's break down the while-loop in parts:

- `it1 != s1.end()` tests that the iterator has not reached the end of the string
- `*it1 != c` dereferences the iterator (obtaining the character at that position) and compares it to `c`
- `++count[(unsigned char)*it1++];` increases the `count` array at the index given by the current character, and also moves the iterator to the next position in the string.

So what this does is read characters until reaching the end of the string or encountering the character `c`, and counts all the characters it visited (not including `c`).

This is only the first half of the Dynamic Programming algorithm I outlined in the original answer.  The second half is to then walk through the second string using the same rules and "uncount" all characters visited.

After both strings have been walked to the next occurrence of `c`, the `count` array will contain up-to-date information about whether the number of each character seen so far in each string is equal.  The mask is then updated, and the outer loop continues stepping through those two strings until the iterators reach the end.

Regarding your other question:

> how do i print the content of the count[] out?

Like this:

```
for (char c = FIRST; c <= LAST; ++c)
{
    cout << "count(" << c << ") = " << count[(unsigned char)c] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `it1++`: this is a post-increment statement. This means that the returned value from the operation `it1++` would be the previous value held by `it1` (meaning, before the increment).
2. `*it1++`: the `*` operator, when applied to iterators, accesses its contents. So, here we're accessing the contents of the *previous* iterator (meaning, the one before the increment took place).
3. `(unsigned char)*it1++`: cast the value contained in the *previous* iterator to `unsigned char` (probably from `char`; this is to avoid negative values as an array index).
4. `count[(unsigned char)*it1++]`: use the previous value as an index for the `count` array.
5. `++count[(unsigned char)*it1++]`: this is a pre-increment statement. This means that the return value will be the result of incrementing the value contained at the given index. Since the array is default initialized using braces (`{}`), all values will initially evaluate to `0`. So, adding:
6. `cout << ++count[(unsigned char)*it1++] << "\n";` will print the actual count for that letter, with a minimum of `1` since it starts at `0` and it's a pre-increment.

Comment: Thanks Paddy.  This is one of this year USACO silver problem.  I use Python and failed the contest.  =(  I google search and find your previous answer and like to learn how your algorithm works.  C++ is quite difficult to understand.

Comment: @paddy is the buddy above xD

Comment: lol hello...  err you're welcome.  If you want to learn how the algorithm works, why don't you read the original Stack Overflow answer where I derive the entire thing in front of your eyes?

Comment: HI Paddy, int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};  why does the count array need to be initialized using 1<< CHAR_BIT and what does that mean?

Comment: I did read it and spend many hours.  but don't quite understand the C++ syntax.  I did understand your algorithm but I like to learn C++ now as it is a faster language.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char` value, which is 8 on most architectures.  So `1 << 8` shifts a 1 to the left by 8 binary places.  This means a value of 256 -- the total number of possible `char` values.  Doing it like this means you don't have to care about out-of-range characters, and you don't need to subtract `'a'` from things (to get an index starting at 0 -- instead just have the index start at 'a').  If you have more clarifications, it would be respectful to ask them on my answer, not somebody else's.

Comment: I am sorry.  I did not realize that your original post is in stackoverflow.  I just google it and find it on the internet.  If not, I will just ask it on your orignial post instead of doing a new post.  again, sorry for doing that.